# Update the number of comments without refreshing the cache

Tags: 7, caching, comments

I am running a local installation of Drupal 7 with the Disqus module installed.

I have created a view with a list of "blog" nodes, and the number of comments displaying through the view. The number of comments in my view does not refresh/update without clearing the cache in Drupal.

Is there a specific way to do this for Disqus, or automatically refresh the Drupal cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, you need ESI or AJAX to do what you want.

This will help you get there, but I don't believe any of the below modules will do exactly what you're looking for.
http://drupal.org/project/esi
http://drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks